# Efficient way to sort/organize images?

Tags: windows, images, website, sorting

I've built a site for someone who has about 100,000 clients, each with their own 'listing' which is searchable.

When you click on a listing for more details, each listing may have anywhere from 0-6 images displayed, for logo and up to 5 products.

There are about 400,000 images in the folder total. I don't have experience with even close to this many images. How slow will it be to open the listing/display the image? I've thought to try to at least split them up into product 1 images, product 2 images, logos, etc. Is there any type of best practice for this type of thing?

I can organize listing images that come in in the future however I want (probably by date uploaded or created similar to wordpress), but since I just transferred these clients, all 100,000 listings were created at nearly the same time.

Basically I have an idea of what things can probably be done, but this seems like too big a thing to just try to cleverly work around with random ideas that pop into my head, with no validation that it will work.

Something that may be important to note is that there are most likely a large amount (guesstimating maybe 20%) of listings/images of older clients that they don't have anymore, or that aren't being used at all.

Thanks for any help in advance! (using windows ec2 instance/ms sql/dotnetnuke if it matters)

Answer (score 1):

You are right to worry about performance with such a big directory.  The simplest solution, which wouldn't require linking with the actual data or complex analysis is to make sub directories based on the filenames.

The exact way to split them actually depends on what the filenames look like but it could be as simple as doing 2-3 levels with the first characters of the file name.